# Seeking reference for a theorem of Woodin

Tags: set-theory

Where has Woodin proved that consistency of super-Reinhardt cardinal implies consistency of Reinhardt cardinal together with $DC_{\lambda}$ where $\lambda$ is the least fixed point of the elementary embedding $j$ witnessing the Reinhardtness of the cardinal above the critical point?

Comment: Asking for a Woodin reference? Statistically speaking, "unpublished".

Comment: Hugh has shown this result in seminars a number of times. I have notes on it (somewhere...), for instance. In print, I am actually not sure he published this exact version, but a close relative established following similar techniques can be found in "Suitable extender models. I", see Theorem 226.